# name is not in the sudoers file:  fedora for virtualbox guest addition on max OSX

Tags: macos, virtualbox, fedora

i'm trying to run the following program using on my VM using VirtualBox (i'm on a mac running OS X and the VM is running fedora):

```
VBoxLinuxAddiitons.run
```

I keep getting an error message saying user is "not in the sudoers file."

This whole thing is an effort to change the screen resolution on my VM.

Do I need to change my password, or add a new one?  Not really sure what to do here.

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Log in to your VM as root.
2. run visudo
3. Add a line `yourusername ALL=(ALL) ALL`

Alternatively, you could just run VBoxLinuxAdditions.run script while logged in as root.

Comment: running the file as root did the trick.  I am, however, still stuck as I don't what to do now.  Once the goest addition is installed, how do actually change the screen resolution?